# Score not adding up correctly in game

Tags: java, android, random

In the program, I have two random values (loadG4 and rbvalue). These values are set to 4 buttons, rbvalue to 3 and loadg4 to one (loadg4 overrides on of the rbvalue buttons). They are randomly generated and assigned to a button by random. Any other details are clearly shown in the code below.

Here's my code:

```
final Random rbselection = new Random();
    final int rbselector = rbselection.nextInt(4);
    final Button[] selectrb = new Button[4];
    selectrb[0] = rb1;
    selectrb[1] = rb2;
    selectrb[2] = rb3;
    selectrb[3] = rb4;

int score = 0;
final Random GenerateG4 = new Random();
final int[] loadG4 = {GenerateG4.nextInt(10)};
final Random randoms1 = new Random();
final TextView number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);

            number.setText(""+ loadG4[0]);
            for(int allrbA=0; allrbA<4; allrbA++) {
                int rbvalue = randoms1.nextInt(9);
                if (rbvalue== loadG4[0]) {
                    rbvalue=9;
                }
                selectrb[allrbA].setText(""+rbvalue);
            }
            selectrb[rbselector].setText(""+ loadG4[0]);

            if (score<4) {
                for (int allrbA = 0; allrbA < 4; allrbA++) {
                    final int rbselector = rbselection.nextInt(4);
                    selectrb[allrbA].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            String getrbvalue = (String) selectrb[rbselector].getText();
                            loadG4[0] = GenerateG4.nextInt(10);
                            number.setText("" + loadG4[0]);
                            for (int allrbA = 0; allrbA < 4; allrbA++) {
                                int rbvalue = randoms1.nextInt(9);
                                if (rbvalue == loadG4[0]) {
                                    rbvalue = 9;
                                }
                                selectrb[allrbA].setText("" + rbvalue);
                            }
                            final int rbselector = rbselection.nextInt(4);
                            selectrb[rbselector].setText("" + loadG4[0]);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            if (score<4) {
                for (int allrbA = 0; allrbA < 4; allrbA++) {
                    final int rbselector = rbselection.nextInt(4);
                    selectrb[rbselector].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            String getrbvalue = (String) selectrb[rbselector].getText();
                            int finalisesrbvalue = Integer.valueOf(getrbvalue);
                            if (finalisesrbvalue == loadG4[0]) {
                                score++;
                                int loadG4 = GenerateG4.nextInt(10);
                                number.setText("" + loadG4);
                                for (int allrbA = 0; allrbA < 4; allrbA++) {
                                    int rbvalue = randoms1.nextInt(9);
                                    if (rbvalue == loadG4) {
                                        rbvalue = 9;
                                    }
                                    selectrb[allrbA].setText("" + rbvalue);
                                }
                                final int rbselector = rbselection.nextInt(4);
                                selectrb[rbselector].setText("" + loadG4);
                            }

                            else {
                                loadG4[0] = GenerateG4.nextInt(10);
                                number.setText("" + loadG4[0]);
                                for (int allrbA = 0; allrbA < 4; allrbA++) {
                                    int rbvalue = randoms1.nextInt(9);
                                    if (rbvalue == loadG4[0]) {
                                        rbvalue = 9;
                                    }
                                    selectrb[allrbA].setText("" + rbvalue);
                                }
                                final int rbselector = rbselection.nextInt(4);
                                selectrb[rbselector].setText("" + loadG4[0]);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

My issue is that the score output is disordered, despite how many times the user clicks the button storing loadG4. This button and the value of loadG4 are constantly changing, as shown above. If I count what should be 6 points, I may get 2 points or 3 points, for example. The user gets awarded a point for the wrong reason, and I'm not sure what it is. My intention is for the program to add a point each time the user clicks the button holding the current loadG4 value, as you'd expect.

I'd appreciate it if anyone could explain what the root of my issue is, *and how it could be resolved*. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you further explain what the code is supposed to do, compared to what it actually does incorrectly?  It might also help if all the variable declarations were included.

Comment: @nasch Of course. Whilst I believe I've mentioned everything key, I'll give a summary in this comment: There are 4 buttons and 4 random numbers for 0-8 which are generated and put randomly in each button. rbvalue is put 4 times (random each time) into all 4 buttons. LoadG4 then replaces one rbvalue in a random button. If an rbvalue is equal to loadG4, it'll be set to 9 to ensure it's never the same as LOADG4. If the user clicks the button with LoadG4 in it, they get a point. They're meant to get a point whenever they click a button containing LoadG4, and that button is random each time.

Comment: @nasch Additional code added at the top. Hopefully this'll help you make sense of my problem, thank you.

Comment: How's about you starting back over the making only one `new Random()` because that's all you really need?

Comment: @cricket_007 Sorry it's hard for me to understand exactly what you're suggesting here, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Looking at the top of the code, I see a total of three `new Random()` objects, which suggests to me that you don't understood why you have more than one

Comment: @cricket_007 If you read my post and code, you'll see why I need three separate randoms.

Comment: No, you really don't. `GenerateG4.nextInt` can generate a new random value everytime it's called. `randoms1.nextInt` will also do the same, but may even be the exact same. That's how random generators work, and you only need one. The name of it is not important too

Comment: And I see you have both `loadG4[0] = GenerateG4.nextInt` and `int loadG4 = GenerateG4.nextInt`, and it is very unclear which is correct under what circumstances

Comment: @cricket_007 I think you are on to something, but I can't exactly interpret how you would like me to represent this in my code. Could you please post an answer with a full explanation and any necessary alterations to my code? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know how to answer this because I still don't understand what results you expect. You never output the value of the score anywhere, so how do you know it's incorrect?